# Null parameter using Ajax.BeginForm iso Html.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Got a controller method handling a file upload:

```
AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult FileUpload(int id, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
    if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0 && ...)
    ...
}
```

When I use Html.BeginForm it all works fine. Replacing the Html.BeginForm with Ajax.BeginForm results in a null value for uploadFile (de 2nd parameter of the method above):

```
<div id="ajaxDocumentUpload">
@{ using (Ajax.BeginForm("FileUpload", "ProjectDocument", FormMethod.Post, 
           new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "UploadSuccess" }, 
           new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  {
    <div>
        <input type=file accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" name="uploadFile">     
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="@Model.ProjectId"/>
    </div>

    <input id=btnUpdateAttachment type=submit value="Upload">
  } 
}
</div>
```

Any idea what is wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You passed incompatible parameters to `Ajax.BeginForm()`. Use this instead:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("FileUpload", "ProjectDocument", null, 
    new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "UploadSuccess" }, 
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
```

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470626%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: Replacing FormMethod.Post by null has no positive effect, unfortunately. Parameter uploadFile is still null (and id is still fine).